# How resolve Lagrange equation ?

Tags: euler-lagrange-equation

How I can resolve this taks? I complety green in differential equations 
$y = xy' +y'^5$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please write further explanation (i.e. your attempt or idea)

Comment: Hi what have you done so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you ar *complety green in differential equations*, I suppose that the solution could be simple such as polynomials.

Considering the equation , **suppose** that $y$ is a polynomial of degree $n$. So, $y'$ is  a polynomial of degree $n-1$.

Comparing the degrees of lhs and rhs, we would have
$$n=[1+(n-1)]+5\times(n-1)=6n-5$$ So,$\cdots ???$